# What is web authentication in React Native Auth0?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, auth0

I'm reading the following documentation on Auth0 1.6.0: https://github.com/auth0/react-native-auth0

It indicates that you should add a certain section of code only if you're "using web authentication". I'm making a mobile app, so I don't know if that means I'm not using web authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web authentication doesn't mean your app has to be a web app; it just means you're authenticating the user with the Auth0 web server.